# how to show tags when you hover and how to darken a picture when you hover?

Tags: html, css, tags

so I have this theme (http://gyapo.tumblr.com/search/teardrop) and it doesn't have the option to show tags when you hover or to darken pictures and gifs when you hover.

I'd like to make the tags show like in this theme ( http://thprev01.tumblr.com/)

can anybody help me please?

Comment: please paste code of what you have tried.

Comment: Please remember that if you found the answer you've been looking for, just tick it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a font-size transition, using CSS3 technology. Just add this into your custom CSS:

```
#tags{
    font-size: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 1s;
    -moz-transition: font-size 1s;
    -o-transition: font-size 1s;
    -ms-transition: font-size 1s;
    transition: font-size 1s;
}

.post:hover #tags{
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#element:hover {
    /*your style here*/
}
#element:hover #element-you-want-to-style {
    /*your style here*/
}
```

reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
img:hover
{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
</style>
```